# Merge happens in reverse way while using GitHub

Tags: github, merge, branch, conflict

trying to merge `branch:community` into `dev` (`community` -> `dev`).

However, without conflict-solving process, some of the files in 'dev' are automatically merged into 'branch:community'. (some files : `dev` -> `community`)
So I cannot update my new files into `dev` branch..

Why is this problem happening? and how can I fix it?

This problem happens during PR , merge process.
Tried making another new branch which has same content in it, and merge again but same problem happens again

- co-working now, so cannot do force work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.